# Python add a function that loops through field

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, calculation

In Excel i have used a calculation like below:
0.16667*10^((C15-121.1)/10). The calculation is placed on D14.

[The dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x61k.png)

In the picture i want to do on the column "0" on index 0 the following calculation:
=0.16667*10^((**91.03**-121.1)/10). This means that the temp on index 1 is used for the calculation for the column "0" on index 0. This has to be like this for the whole column

Further explanation:

```
    Temp     Calculation
0   90.01    0.16667*10^((91.03-121.1)/10)
1   91.03    0.16667*10^((95.06-121.1)/10)
2   95.06    0.16667*10^((100.07-121.1)/10)
3   100.07   0.16667*10^((103.00-121.1)/10)
4   103.00
```

So look at the calculation in the DF. the temparatures in the calculation are one Temp above the current index

EDIT:

```
List1= [90.01, 91.03, 95.06, 100.07, 103.50]

test = pd.DataFrame(List1, columns=["Temp"])
```

then i want to add the calculation:

```
test["calculation"] = 0.16667*10^((test["Temp"][1:]-121.1)/10)
```

this gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rxor' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

EDIT 2:

```
test["calculation"] = 0.16667*10**((test["Temp"][1:]-121.1)/10).reset_index()


test returns:

    Temp    calculation
0   90.01   1.6667
1   91.03   16.6670
2   95.06   166.6700
3   100.07  1666.7000
4   103.50  NaN
```

The way the calculation goes is good. But the outcome is different. when the temp is 100.07 the outcome has to be 0.001314. see below:

```
test2 = 0.16667*10**((100.07-121.1)/10)

out: 0.0013147931580348442
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference whole columns in dataframes and perform any calculations on them as you want.

```
df["answer"] = 0.16667*10**((df["Temp"]-121.1)/10)
```

EDIT:

I understand now that you want to use the next row to calculate the current row;
You can treat pandas series as lists and index them as such, i.e. [1:]

```
df["calculation"] = 0.16667*10**((df["Temp"][1:]-121.1)/10).reset_index()
```

This will leave the last spot in the calculation column as NaN, but you can change this manually if you wish afterwards.

EDIT2: Oversight, ^ is xor in python, ** is equivalent to power.
.reset_index() is needed as otherwise the offset will be at the start, not end of the dataframe

EDIT3:

Using the code

```
test["calculation"] = 0.16667*10**((test["Temp"][1:]-121.1)/10).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I obtain the result

```
     Temp  calculation
0   90.01     0.000164
1   91.03     0.000415
2   95.06     0.001315
3  100.07     0.002896
4  103.50          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the df["temp"] has to be one index up to the index where the outcome has to be.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that i understand. Can you edit your post and put in your expected output?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Final question ... i have updated my code and it gives the following error: TypeError: Cannot perform 'rxor' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: You'll have to post your code to let me have an idea of what's happening in that section

Comment: Ah, that was an oversight on my part, apologies! ^ is the xor operator in python, ** is the power operator. I also added the reset_index() function to fix the indices.

Comment: Can you please look at my last edit, there is one thing wrong

Comment: Make sure you use reset_index, as i specified in the edit. `df["calculation"] = 0.16667*10**((df["Temp"][1:]-121.1)/10).reset_index()`

Comment: The outcome is not what the formula has to do. look at the edit

Comment: Thats it ! I really appreciate your help !